# Redirect domain to another with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

my first domain (www.domain-a.com) redirects to the root folder of the server and opens my website. Now I want the second domain (www.domain-b.com) to redirect to www.domain-a.com/site2.htm. Is there a way I can do that with htaccess, without using php?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you managed to write any rewrite rules so far?

Comment: I just found out how to redirect both domains to something different - but I found now way to differentiate between www.domain-a.com and www.domain-b.com. The only option I am aware of is to create a subfolder for domain b with an index.php which redirects using php.

Comment: Post the current rules you have in the question. And are these domains on the same server or not?

Comment: I tried the following:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-b.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain-a.com/site2.htm [R=301,L]`
Yes, the domains are on the same server and both point to root at the moment..

Comment: Well.. my mistake, sorry! I forgot to delete the cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-b.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain-a.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

More about it: http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://domain-a.com/cms/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-b.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain-a.com/$1 [R=301,L] - I also tried RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain-a.com/site2.htm [R=301,L]